# Vinyl flooring on a 100+ year old home with no level floors

Tags: vinyl-flooring

Is it possible to install interlocking vinyl flooring on a home with not exactly level floors?
The home is 100+ years old and would require a major upgrade to make the floors completely level.
I'm looking to make an economical upgrade to the bathroom floor which currently has hideous sheet vinyl floors.
Can I use interlocking vinyl floors on a surface that is not exactly level?

Answer (score 1):

Floors don't have to be level for click-lock flooring, it just needs to be flat.  Manufacturers will give you the maximum floor change per foot.  I suggest that if you have small dips that are outside the manufacturers ranges you fill those with a self-leveling compound.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DMoore self-leveling compound will not help him, in fact it can cause more damage than good if applied on this type of floor...with the rest I agree. If you want to fix dips you better use something like putty

Comment: @pythonstarter what kind of putty do you use on wood sub-flooring to fill in low spots?